# Regex to match lines not containing a word

Tags: regex, shell, grep, regex-negation

I was trying to create a regex, to be used in a grep statement to match lines that do not contain a word. In the example below I have the words uhu, uhuu, uhuuu, uhuuu one in each line. I used an echo to do that in one command. Results are:

```
line1 = uh - end
line2 = uhu - end
line3 = uhuu - end
line4 = uhuuu - end
line5 = uhuuuu - end
```

Never mind the line number and the end word. So, I wanted to grep uhuu's with 2 and 4 repetitions only, that is line 3 and 5. I tried:

```
echo -e 'line1 = uh - end\nline2 = uhu - end\nline3 = uhuu - end\nline4 = uhuuu - end\nline5 = uhuuuu - end' | grep -E 'uh(u{2}|u{4})'
line3 = uhuu - end
line4 = uhuuu - end
line5 = uhuuuu - end
```

It brings line 3 and 5, but also line 4 because uhuuu has 2 u's, plus a 3rd one. So my question is, using Regex, is it possible to exclude that 4th line taking into account only the 'uhuuu' word?

I know I could accomplish this with a pipe and grep -v at the end of everything but I was wondering if this could be done using RegEx.

I checked this link but couldn find a way to make it work for my case. Thank you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word#_=_)

Comment: try egrep -v "uh(u{2}|u{4})"

Comment: @Devian That suffers from the same problem: `uhu{2}` matches with at least two trailing `u`s and so will match longer items.

Comment: it seems like it is, my fault

Comment: how about using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) something like `grep -P 'uh(?:u{2}|u{4})(?!u)'` ([see demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eZNL0z/1)).

Comment: Thanks @bobblebubble, this works like a charm, even though I don't understand yet how lookahead (lookaround) works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a word boundary meta character after grouping:

```
grep -E 'uh(u{2}|u{4})\b'
```

Comment: That's right @revo, I had tried it before but had even forgotten. Thank you